# Extract data from ezplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, extract, matlab-figure

I am trying to extract data from an `ezplot`, but when I plot the extracted data, I don't get the same graph (`a` and `b` are different)...

Could anybody elaborate on what's wrong?

Here is the code:

```
h = @(x,y)(x-((1/0.0175)*(y/5500)*(1+(y/5500)^9)))
a = ezplot(h,[0,700,0,7000]);
t = get(a,'xdata');
M = get(a,'ydata');
theta = transpose(t)
figure
b = plot(theta,M)
```

`ezplot` produces

[image: ezplot]

whilst `plot` produces

[image: plot]

This is what I get by extracting from the contour, there is still a straight line [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29X51.png)

Comment: I suggest adding two images, to see how they differ. Are the axis limits the same? Why not use `plot` directly though?

Answer (score 2):

[`ezplot`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) returns a `contour` object. To extract the `x` and `y` data you need to use `get(a,'contourMatrix')`. Then the `x` data will be in the first column and the `y` data in the second column as

```
t = get(a,'contourMatrix');
x = t(1, :);
y = t(2, :);
```

Putting this altogether for your example we get

```
h = @(x,y)(x-((1/0.0175)*(y/5500)*(1+(y/5500)^9)))
a = ezplot(h,[0,700,0,7000]);

t = get(a,'contourMatrix');
x = t(1, :);
y = t(2, :);

figure;
b = plot(x, y);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('({x}-(({1}/{0.0175}) ({y}/{5500}) ({1}+({y}/{5500})^{9}))) = {0}');
```

The resulting `ezplot` is

[image: ezplot]

and the same from `plot`

[image: plot]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the explanation. I tried with only your code and I get the curve + the straight line on the same figure ! I cleared everything before running it

Comment: But it actually works when I add '.' after the plot !

Comment: Execute `close all; clear all;` beforehand and make sure you only run my code and nothing else. It works perfectly for me as you can see by the 2 images.

Comment: @user3767791 If my answer helped you I would appreciate it if you could upvote it or [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the [x and y axis values](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html#zmw57dd0e128148) in calling `get(a,'xdata')` and `get(a,'ydata')`. That is the reason you're getting the straight line. 
Try this instead:

```
h = @(x,y)(x-((1/0.0175)*(y/5500)*(1+(y/5500)^9)));
ezplot(h,[0,700,0,7000]);
a= get(gca,'Children');
l=get(a,'Children');
t = get(l,'xdata');
M = get(l,'ydata');
theta = transpose(t);
figure
b = plot(theta,M);
```

Sources:

1. [Handle Graphics: Modifying Plots](http://www.mit.edu/people/abbe/matlab/handle.html)
2. [How do I extract data from MATLAB figures?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100687-how-do-i-extract-data-from-matlab-figures)